# How to include fractal transformed objects directly to collection meta without data key

Tags: php, json, key, serialization

I'm using league/fractal with JsonApiSerializer,

I've got users collection for json output.
Now I want to add some filters data to this json response (like users count for current filters).

I got this:

```
$resource = new Collection($dataProvider->getData(), new UserTransformer());
```

//the only way to include some not directly linked data i found is using setMeta():

```
    $resource->setMetaValue('projects', $dataProvider->getProjects());
    $resource->setMetaValue('somes',    $dataProvider->getTasks());
```

But! 'projects' & 'somes' collections (yes, they are collection too) also included with 'data' key in it.

So, I've got this structure:

```
{
    'data' => [
         {//user1},{//user2},...
    ],
    'meta' => {
         'projects' => {
              'data' => {...}
         },
         'somes' => {
              'data' => {...}
         }
    }
}
```

but I want something like:

```
{
    'data' => [
         {//user1},{//user2},...
    ],
    'meta' => {
         'projects' => {...}, //there is no 'data' key
         'somes' => {...}     //there is no 'data' key
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda hack but works fine without refactor Scope class which hardcoded in fractal's League\Fractal\Manager::createData() and is only way to use your own Scope class realization is to overload this method in Manager's extension.

```
<?php
use League\Fractal\Serializer\JsonApiSerializer;

/**
 * Class EmbedSerializer
 */
class EmbedSerializer extends JsonApiSerializer
{
    const RESOURCE_EMBEDDED_KEY = 'embedded';

    /**
     * Serialize a collection.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $resourceKey === self::RESOURCE_EMBEDDED_KEY ? $data : [$resourceKey ?: 'data' => $data];
    }

    /**
     * Serialize an item.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $resourceKey === self::RESOURCE_EMBEDDED_KEY ? $data : [$resourceKey ?: 'data' => [$data]];
    }
}
```

So, now i could use it like:

```
    /** @var $this->fractal League\Fractal\Manager */
    $this->fractal->setSerializer(new EmbedSerializer());

    $projectsCollection = $this->fractal->createData(
        new Collection($projects, new UserProjectTransformer(), 'embedded')
    )->toArray();

    $resource = new Collection($users, new UserTransformer());
    $resource->setMetaValue('projects', $projectsCollection);
```

That's all u need. Hope this will be helpful.